# MongoDB - How to find array which only contains the specified value

Tags: arrays, mongodb, search, mongodb-query

Suppose I have the following documents

```
segments
{
  "name":"S1",
},
{
  "name":"S2",
},
{
  "name":"S3",
}
```

And users

```
users
{
  "id":1234.
  "segments":["S1","S2","S3"]
}
{
  "id":1235.
  "segments":["S1"]
}
{
  "id":1237.
  "segments":["S2"]
}
{
  "id":1236.
  "segments":["S1","S2"]
}
```

If i do users.find({ "segments" : "S2" }), it brings all the docs with field "S2" in it.

What I'm looking for is, array with JUST the value S2.
I'm looking for this output:

```
{
  "id":1237.
  "segments":["S2"]
}
```

Because it ONLY has S2 which i'm looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`$elemMatch`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) projection

```
db.collection.find({
  segments: ["S2"]
})
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried your solution, but it returned those sets too which contained "S2" as well as others. (i.e. "S2" and "S1")...  Thank you for your help though

Comment: I'm sorry you might have missed my requirement. What I'm looking for is just document with ID 1237 as it is the only document which has S2 only.(just one element)